# How to remove the style tag using asp.net

Tags: coding-style, tags

I want to remove all style attribute in html tags using asp.net...

```
string source=@" <div style="font-size: 12pt;"> Hello world</div> <style id=fll  margin:19px auto;text-align:center"></style>";
```

I want the result like this:

```
  <div>Hello world </div>
```

For that i am using,

string expn =@"(?i)<(table|tr|td)(?:\s+(?:""[^""]*""|'[^']*'|[^""'>])*)?>";
 return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(source, expn, string.Empty);

I dont know which one is using,
Tell me the query what i have to use for this one....

Answer (score 0):

This should work (though I don't understand the style **tag** at the end of your example):

```
string source="<div style=\"font-size: 12pt;\"> Hello world</div>";
string pattern = "style=\".*\"";
string result = Regex.Replace(source, pattern, "");
```